# What does the retryAfterResize: for (;;) syntax mean in IdentityHashMap source code in Java

Tags: java, syntax

In `put` method of [IdentityHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html), I see a syntax which I've never seen before.

[source code link](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/847d7a6aef45/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/IdentityHashMap.java)

```
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        final Object k = maskNull(key);

        retryAfterResize: for (;;) {
            final Object[] tab = table;
            final int len = tab.length;
            int i = hash(k, len);

            for (Object item; (item = tab[i]) != null;
                 i = nextKeyIndex(i, len)) {
                if (item == k) {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                        V oldValue = (V) tab[i + 1];
                    tab[i + 1] = value;
                    return oldValue;
                }
            }

            final int s = size + 1;
            // Use optimized form of 3 * s.
            // Next capacity is len, 2 * current capacity.
            if (s + (s << 1) > len && resize(len))
                continue retryAfterResize;

            modCount++;
            tab[i] = k;
            tab[i + 1] = value;
            size = s;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

`retryAfterResize: for (;;)`  and `continue retryAfterResize;` What does this syntax mean? Is there any terminology(Java doc) for this syntax? Thanks.

Comment: @Ivar Thank you so much. That's it. I didn't see this before.

Comment: I wonder why they used a  label: the `continue` isn't in a nested loop, so it the label isn't necessary.